# Extract string from a cell and put it in a new data frame R

Tags: r, regex, extract

In a R project, I want to extract strings from a data frame which a column is like

```
"A|B|C"
"B|Z"
"I|P"
...
```

I want to have a new data frame with column `A B C Z I P`
I think to make it with a for and a `gsub`, but it is not easy because the pattern extract the `|` and I am not sure if it is the best and elegant way to do this kind of task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

starting with the dataframe df, with base R we can try the following:

```
data.frame(col=unique(unlist(strsplit(as.character(df$col), split='\\|'))))
#  col
#1   A
#2   B
#3   C
#4   Z
#5   I
#6   P
```

or with dplyr

```
df %>% 
  mutate(col = strsplit(col, "\\|")) %>% 
  unnest(col) %>% unique 

#     col
#   (chr)
#1     A
#2     B
#3     C
#4     Z
#5     I
#6     P
```

**data**

```
df <- data.frame(col=c("A|B|C",
                       "B|Z",
                       "I|P"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

If you want them to be the names of the columns, try this:

```
symbols <- unique(unlist(strsplit(as.character(df$col), split='\\|')))
df <- data.frame(matrix(vector(), 0, length(symbols),
                  dimnames=list(c(), symbols)), stringsAsFactors=F)
df
#[1] A B C Z I P
#<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

Comment: Thanks, the problem, now, is to make the A,B,C names of columns and not rows in one column

Answer (score 2):

With a combination of `strsplit`,`unlist` and `unique` you can do:

```
#Steps:
#1) split each element of column with separator as "|"
#2) combine output for all items with unlist
#3) retain unique elements of those


vec = c("A|B|C","B|Z","I|P")

newDF = data.frame(newCol = unique(unlist(lapply(vec,function(x) unlist(strsplit(x,"[|]")) ))),
stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

newDF$newCol
#[1] "A" "B" "C" "Z" "I" "P"
```

Comment: `unique(scan(textConnection(vec), 'character', sep = '|'))`

Comment: `data.frame(char = unique(unlist(strsplit(vec, "|", fixed = TRUE))))`

Answer (score 1):

We can use `cSplit`

```
library(splitstackshape)
unique(cSplit(df1, "V1", "|", "long"), by = "V1")
```

#### data

```
df1 <- data.frame(V1 =  c("A|B|C","B|Z","I|P"))
```

Answer (score 1):

The `scan` function with the text parameter input appears suited for this task:

```
 st <- c("A|B|C","B|Z","I|P")
 scan(text=st, what="", sep="|")
Read 7 items
[1] "A" "B" "C" "B" "Z" "I" "P"
```

It wasn't clear to me from your problem description or example how you wanted this to be aligned with the original 3 row dataframe.

Comment: When I do scan(text = st[i,3], what = "", sep = "|") I got "argument 'text' incorrect"; where "i" is the number of row (there is a lot of it) and 3 is the column where are the letters.

Comment: @Chènevis maybe your text is a factor instead of character